# execute an ABAP report from other screen

Tags: abap

I have 2 screens, 1000 in which the execute button is there and 0200 in which i am request some dynamic parameters. so now i have to first save the changes in 0200 and then i come back to screen 1000 and then execute the program.

screen 1000
[image]

screen 0200
[image]
as soon as i save it i come back to screen 1000 and then i have to press execute button.

I  achieved this by calling the page number in the save function but if i do that then i cant come back to the selection screen again, so i was looking for an alternate solution.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your definition of the selection screen and PBO/PAI of them?

Comment: Give us the code

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to input the dynamic parameters, at least in this example, in a sub-screen popup, so you'd never actually leave Screen 1000.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer place the all parameters in selection screen in your case. However, if you want to do it your way, then you should write "leave to screen 1000" at the button action in PAI of the 0200 screen.

[Here](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/1946930) is a similar problem.